# Circular Visualization in Python with Piled Ranges

Tags: python, matplotlib, range, visualization, circular-reference

How would one create a circular visualization (genome representation) in matplotlib (or other package) and pile up  pieces with percentage ranges. For example, if I have three genes, I would like to pile the three genes onto a circular map with a length 0-1. Some offset would be needed to distinguish individual ranges.

Gene 1: .1 - .25 
Gene 2: .15 - .3 
Gene 3: .6 - .68

### Desired Output Below:

[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reference, this is how to do it using "only" `matplotlib`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data={
    0:{'name':'Gene 1', 'start': .10, 'end': .25, 'offset': 0.1, 'color': 'blue'},
    1:{'name':'Gene 2', 'start': .15, 'end': .30, 'offset': 0.2, 'color': 'orange'},
    2:{'name':'Gene 3', 'start': .60, 'end': .68, 'offset': 0.1, 'color': 'green'}
}


## setup the figure:
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1) # make it go clockwise
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N') # put "0" at top
# remove the labels
ax.set_xticks([]) 
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.spines['polar'].set_visible(False)
LW = 3.0 ## setting the linewidth globally for fine-tuning


def add_bg_circle(ax):
    """ adds the central circle with top notch """
    # the circle
    circle_x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,200)
    circle_y = np.array([1.0 for x in circle_x])
    ax.plot(circle_x,circle_y,c="k",linewidth=LW)
    # the top notch
    line_y = np.linspace(1.0,1.1) ## change length of the top line here
    line_x = np.array([0 for y in line_y])
    ax.plot(line_x,line_y,c="k",linewidth=LW)
    # the text
    ax.text(0.0,1.15,"0",ha="center",va="center")
    
add_bg_circle(ax)    

## plot the line segments:
for (k,v) in data.items():
    xs = np.linspace(v['start']*2*np.pi , v['end']*2*np.pi, 200)
    ys = np.array([(1.0 + v['offset']) for x in xs])

    ax.plot(xs, ys, linewidth=LW, label=v['name'])

_inner_lim = 0.5 # keep this below the value for the main circle at 1.0
_outer_lim = 1.3 # adjust to include all plotted segments
ax.set_ylim(_inner_lim,_outer_lim) 

# plt.legend() # optional
# plt.savefig("dna_circle.png")
plt.show()
```

yields:

[image: plot result]

Comment: Wow! I like the ability to set the offset as well! Thank you very much @Asmus

Comment: Good job @Asmus, I like your solution with Matplotlib only, and it doesn't actually look very complex!

Answer (score 2):

I would say that it's not gonna be easy to draw this using Matplotlib, but I assume you would be happy with other libraries as you claimed "or other packages" in your question.

I will show my method to draw this using Plotly. You could simply run `pip install plotly` to have this library.

I would use a polar axis to draw the circular chart, which makes everything easier.

Firstly, let's define a function for getting the radius `r` repeated in certain times together with the `theta` values. Please note that `num_points` is a constant value that makes your chart more "smooth" if you set it higher.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

def get_theta(pct, num_points=360):
  start = pct[0] * 360
  length = (pct[1] - pct[0]) * 360
  step = 360 / num_points
  return np.arange(start, start + length + step, step)
```

I will hard code your gene list. In your case, I assume you don't have to do this :)

```
# Hard-code your gene list
gene_list = [
  [0.1, 0.25],
  [0.15, 0.3],
  [0.6, 0.68]
]
```

Then, the code to draw the circular chart.

```
# Get radial scale
max_r = 1 + (len(gene_list) + 1) * 0.1

# Create a figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Create the main circle
fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
  r=[1]*360,
  theta=get_theta([0, 1]),
  mode='lines',
  line_color='black',
  line_width=3
))

# Create the zero indicator
fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
  r=[1, max_r - 0.1],
  theta=[0, 0],
  mode='lines',
  line_color='black',
  line_width=3
))

# Loop the gene list to add all the gene cirles 
for index, circle in enumerate(gene_list):
  fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
    r = [1 + (index + 1) * 0.1] * 360,
    theta = get_theta(circle),
    mode='lines',
    line_width=3
  ))

# Configure the layout based on the requirements.
fig.update_layout(
  polar=dict(
      angularaxis=dict(
        rotation=90,
        direction="clockwise",
        showticklabels=True,
        showgrid=False
      ),
      radialaxis=dict(
        range=[0, 1 + (len(gene_list) + 1) * 0.1],
        showticklabels=False,
        visible=False
      )
  ),
  paper_bgcolor='white'
)

# Show the figure
fig.show()
```

Here is the chart that the code generated.

[image]

Definitely I can see there is still an issue. Each "gene" segment will not be rendered on the same radius. It's not impossible to replicate your example exactly, but apparently not easy. Hope this is enough for you. If it is really important for you. It might be worth to try to use the step less than `0.1` (find the `0.1` in my code and replace it).

Comment: Hi @Christopher, this is amazing and exactly what I am looking for! Great job, you are a life saver, I have been trying and failing with matplotlib.